# Google Analytics Event tracking: how to avoid sending data for local test?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm testing Google Analytics Event tracking with my local server.

I'm using the debug version of ga.js, [ga_debug.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting?hl=en#gaDebug), in order to print debug text automatically in my browser console.
Furthermore, i set domain name to none, which is supposed not sending the data to your Analytics account ([stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375447/can-you-test-google-analytics-on-a-localhost-address)):

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
...
```

But my events tracked are still sent to my Analytics Account, so my question is how to avoid this?
Is the `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);` disable data sending only for page view and not event tracking?

Thanks for your help,

Xavier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following snippet to your dev environment:

`window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXXX-Y'] = true;`

For more information read https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#disable

Comment: Not too bad :-) Please note your solution skipped debugging text printing. Some debugging datas are still printed on the console which is enough for me (`_gaq.push processing "_trackEvent" for args: "[Category_Text,Action_Text,2150,,false]": `), but some people might need the whole debugging text. Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: Finally setting domain name to none is useless for local testing?

Comment: Well if the debug output is only printed when there is actual data sent you could set up a new profile on google analytics that you only use for testing purposes

Comment: If I have the dev end production environment open in two different tabs in the same browser, is tracking going to work in prod environment?

Comment: "developement and production environment ", sorry

Comment: That you have them open in different tabs has no effect on the code. Look at the network inspector to see what happens

Comment: I used it a bit different: `window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXX-Y'] = !('https:' == document.location.protocol);`, in my case https is used only in production.