# GA stopped at Track Pageview and not seeing any results coming back

Tags: google-analytics

I am currently experiencing a strange problem. on our QA environment, when I enter a link in CHROME, and view it in GA Debugger, i see

```
_gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-22096768-1]":  ga_debug.js:24

_gaq.push processing "_setDomainName" for args: "[marilyn.ca]":  ga_debug.js:24

_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":  ga_debug.js:24

Track Pageview
```

which is good, but I don't see any more responses coming back after that.  But on my local environment, I do see a GA response coming back.

Any ideas on why? code deployed to both environment are the same. such as the tracking beacon, all the utm parameters, and etc

Please advise.

many thanks

Comment: I followed what Google recommended, put that above the </head> element, it still didn't help though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375447/can-you-test-google-analytics-on-a-localhost-address

Comment: @mike just tried that. I don't think that was what is causing it though. Like I said, the strange thing is as long as I am running a stripped down test page that contains the call to GA, and then all the normal pages I test will work fine, like (http://marilyn.localhost/HealthyEating.aspx) I see the calls being made and it is all good. But as soon as I clear cache, restart the browser, load the URL (http://marilyn.localhost/HealthyEating.aspx) again, I don't see GA tracking anymore. It is behaving really strange

Comment: OK, i used AutoResponder in Fiddler, and verified that it would actually work if it were in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out this one.  we are testing on our QA box. I had to make the following change

_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);

http://analyticsimpact.com/2011/01/20/google-analytics-on-intranets-and-development-servers-fqdn/

It is actually strange because our hosting op informed us they white listed GA on QA box. In any case, that was the fix for my problem