# Google Universal Analytics Localhost Setup

Tags: google-analytics, localhost, google-analytics-api, analytics.js

I'm trying to test GA on localhost after following the suggestions in [Can you test google analytics on a localhost address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375447/can-you-test-google-analytics-on-a-localhost-address/10644663#10644663)

1). but I don't see any data being send to my Google Analytics account when browsing on my localhost server and calling the JS script. I know it's executing the JS. What am I doing wrong? Here is my JS code:

> ```
> (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
> (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
> m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
> })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
>
> ga('create', 'UA-55555555-1', {
>   'cookieDomain': 'none'
> });
>
> ga('send', 'timing', 'jQuery', 'Load Some Test Library', 20, 'Google Test');
> ```

2). Also, I'm confused about GA requiring a default domain to be set under Admin --> Property --> Property Settings. If I declare 'cookieDomain':'none', does that mean the domain as part of my GA account is ignored?

Cheers,

partizan

Comment: I havent tried to test it with localhost but arnt you missing.     ga('create', 'UA-555555-1', 'localhost');
ga('send', 'pageview');

Comment: LindaL, I don't seem to need the lines of code you suggest. I can see the data with the code above now but it took a few hours to reflect it in GA. For testing purposes, is there a way to faster refresh the data in Google Analytics that is sent from my server?

Comment: You can try the real-time reports, but GA data always takes processing time to view.

Comment: I may have miss understood your question.  I read somewhere that it takes Google about 4 or 5 hours to process the hit before you will see it on there site.  Check the real-time reports like Alison S suggested.  I would love to here if it works.  The ability to  test from localhost could be useful.

Comment: A little late to the party, but it does show in real time analytics!