# Local host sandbox - Google Universal analytics code is not working

Tags: magento, google-analytics, analytics

> Note: I tried the existing answers and they are not working

In my local host Magento setup, Google Universal analytics code is not working. I am not able to see the hits in my account. Can anyone tell me what could be the issue ? Below is the code

```
        <!-- BEGIN GOOGLE UNIVERSAL ANALYTICS CODE -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');


    ga('create', '<My Account-Id>', {'cookieDomain':'none'});

    ga('send', 'pageview');

    //]]>
    </script>
    <!-- END GOOGLE UNIVERSAL ANALYTICS CODE -->
```

Comment: Potentially silly question but have you checked that your IP hasn't been filtered out from the IP address filter from GA?

Comment: @ChrisRogers  IP address filter has nothing. Means it does not filter anything and allow all hits in the reports..

Comment: Can you give a pointer as to what was in those previous answers you tried (or simply link to them) ?

Comment: This is what i tried
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375447/can-you-test-google-analytics-on-a-localhost-address  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943786/google-universal-analytics-localhost-setup