# How can I ignore ga() event tracking code throughout my site when I remove google analytics in localhost?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

On localhost, I disable my google analytics code by incorporating it into an if statement like so:

```
var s = window.location + "";

if (s.indexOf('localhost') < 0) {
    //GA universal analytics tracking snippet
}
```

However, throughout my site there are various event tags using `ga('send', 'event', etc...);` - when my GA snippet is disabled on localhost these functions return errors (`Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined`).

Is there a way to disable these functions without putting them all into their own individual if statements? I was thinking some kind of global statement like this might work, but it doesn't:

```
var s = window.location + "";

if (s.indexOf('localhost') > 0) {
    ga = function () {};
}
```

Is there a good best practice for solving this? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be simpler to do this :

```
var ga = ga || (function(){});
```

If `ga` is defined, this does nothing. If it's `undefined`, it sets its value to a no-op function, preventing the error.

But I don't think it's a good idea to disable the script when you develop : it makes one more reason to have an unexpected bug in production. The best practice here would be, in my opinion, to add a filter in Google Analytics. See [Exclude internal traffic](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=en).

Comment: Also, if you "setDomainName" to your production URL, GA will still download, but it won't fire into your account: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375447/can-you-test-google-analytics-on-a-localhost-address

Comment: This worked for me. It's an simple solution when you don't want any tracking code in your local dev environment.