# Google analytics for localhost site

Tags: google-analytics, localhost

I've deployed website that is running on server on local network and I would like to track traffic with Google analytics.

Following code, that was generated by google analytics, is placed in pages that I would like to track

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'cookieDomain': 'none'});        
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

This line of code was modified according to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375447/can-you-test-google-analytics-on-a-localhost-address).

```
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'cookieDomain': 'none'});
```

When I visit my admin page on Google analytics site it says under **Status** that **Tracking is not installed**.

Page was visited from several computers but it seems that page view info is not getting to Google servers.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it seemed that inserted code was enough. It just required some time for google servers to get and process the information.

Answer (score 1):

Another way around would be to add a FQDN to your local `/etc/hosts` file, e.g.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.dev
```

Point your browser to http://localhost.dev/ instead.