# Test Google Analytics on Localhost

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I need to test some custom firing events using Google Analytics. I'd like to test in a local environment.

I've set up my test site using apache with server name: `my-ga-test.localhost/`

According to [Can you test google analytics on a localhost address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375447/can-you-test-google-analytics-on-a-localhost-address) and [Google Analytics docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced), I'm able to adjust my GA code to use:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {
  'cookieDomain': 'none'
});
```

I tried to set up a new account to get a tracking ID for this site, but I'm getting the following error:

> URL ends with an invalid top-level domain name

[image]

How do I generate the code using localhost domain so I can alter the tracking ID code to put on my localhost?

Comment: R u owning the domain? Because I am also the owner of the same domain.

Comment: @SudipPal what do you mean?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The "Website URL" field when creating a new Google Analytics property does not have to be the same as the actual URL that's used in production. It's primarily used for resolving relative links, not for validating hits.

Just change it to something else (like `example.com`), and everything should work fine.

Comment: What if I run my web application both in local & production server simulatenously?

Comment: @user3595632 it doesn't matter, it will work just fine.

Comment: @Phillip Walton Would it be getting data from both?

Comment: @user3595632 you should start a separate question for that since it's unrelated to the original question asked here.

Comment: If you have your application running in development and production, you are better off setting up two views, Site and Site test, and when you call your analytics.js with ```UA-XXXX-Y```, check for the environment and use the proper code. Don't pollute your production data with development data.

Answer (score 4):

I do not recommend the above answer.

I believe the best practice is to use the **Analytics Debug js** on your localhost. Debug prints in console EVERYTHING is doing, including firing events. That way you can check if your code is working or not without sending tracking info to Analytics on Localhost (which makes no sense).

Find out more [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging?hl=en) :)

Comment: This question is specifically about the "Website URL" field when creating a new Account or Property. It has nothing to do with the debug version of `analytics.js`

Comment: I think he created a test view, in which case is okay to have that for testing. From my experience I got numerous insights from having just a testing view  (I do use Analytics Debug js as well).

Comment: And also how do you enter `UA-XXXXX-Y` without going through this step? Analytics Debug JS also needs it